# How to get the root package path using composer

Tags: php, path, package, composer-php, root

I'm developing a PHP component called [php-app-config](https://github.com/robotdance/php-app-config) using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). 
This component, once required by another project, and installed using `composer install`, should look for config files inside the config folder of the [root package](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#root-package), something like `root_package/config/config.yml`.

The `./config/config.yml` should exists only in the root package and not inside the component imported by the "require:" in `composer.json`, as below:

```
▾ root-package/
  ▸ bin/
  ▸ build/
  ▾ config/
    ▸ locales/
      config.yml
  ▸ src/
  ▸ tests/
  ▾ vendor/
    ▸ composer/
    ▸ phpdocumentor/
    ▸ phpspec/
    ▸ phpunit/
    ▾ robotdance/
      ▾ php-app-config/
        ▾ src/                                                                                                                                                                                               
      Config.php -> how to get the root "config/config.yml" path from here?
        ▸ tests/
      composer.json
      composer.lock
      phpunit.xml
      README.md
```

The root package can be a web app or command line utility.
Is there any way to get the root package path using composer? If not, what is the better way?

Comment: I have tried a number of ways and it doesn't seem to be possible outside of the composer run-script context where composer loads into the application. The problem you are experiencing should be solvable using a relative path to your applications php include path. In the example you provided, you should be passing a path from a script I assume is in bin/ which can get the install path using `dirname(__DIR__)`.  Same principal apply's when using public/index.php as the entry point.  All bets are off when using phar as the path overrides are horrifically broken.

Answer (score 21):

Using ReflectionClass:

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass(\Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::class);
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname($reflection->getFileName()));
```

Comment: In new versions of PHP you can simple use `dirname($reflection->getFileName(), 2)` or `dirname($reflection->getFileName(), 3)` instead of `dirname(dirname(`

Answer (score 5):

You can use composer's very own `\Composer\Factory::getComposerFile();` to get to the project root directory:

`$projectRootPath = dirname(\Composer\Factory::getComposerFile());`

And with your case, you can access your `root-package/config/config.yml` by:

`$configYmlPath = $projectRootPath . '/config/config.yml'`

Don't forget to add `composer` to your dependencies for the `\Composer\Factory::class` to be available:

`$ composer require composer/composer`

Comment: As I see it `\Composer\Factory::getComposerFile()` returns the name of the file that Composer will use, not the path to the actual file.
When a webserver exposes the site from a subfolder like `public`, `dirname(\Composer\Factory::getComposerFile())` will include that subfolder even though `composer.json` is not stored there.

Answer (score 2):

- I would suggest "anchoring" your application (web or cli) by defining the root path as a constant.

  When you have for instance a `root-package/src/application.php` file, it should know where it lives, something like `define('APP_ROOT_FOLDER', dirname(__DIR__));` could help. Once the constant is declared, it's available for dependencies, too.

  So, in `/php-app-config/Config.php` you would simply use the constant:

  `$config = APP_ROOT_FOLDER . '/config/config.yml';`

  (Or define a `APP_CONFIG_ROOT_FOLDER` constant which points directly to the config folder of the application.)
- You could also try go some folder levels up from the dependency.

  In `php-app-config/Config.php` you would use `__DIR__`, which is `root-package/vendor/robotdance/php-app-config/src`. Now, you would need to go 4 levels up to reach `root-package/`.

  `$config =  __DIR__.'/../../../../config/config.yml';`

  This will not work out, when your application gets packaged as a PHAR.

---

> Is there any way to get the root package path using Composer?

If you have the Composer object, you can get the path of the vendor directory from the Config object:

```
$vendorPath = $composer->getConfig()->get('vendor-dir');
```

then, go one folder up `$config = dirname($vendorPath) . '/config/config.yml';`

Comment: I tried [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) and it seems to work as intended using the autoloader provided by composer.

Comment: How to get the composer Object? is it something like `use composer\Composer; $composer = Composer::getComposer();` ?

Comment: The snippet that deals with `vendor-dir` only considers the case where it is a directory directly inside the root package. Something like `dist/php` for `vendor-dir` would break. It would be ideal to get the install path from the `InstallationManager`, but there is no special handling for the root package at this time and would return an install path inside the `vendor-dir` when requesting the install location for the root package.  The best way I've found is to do `dirname(\Composer\Factory::getComposerFile());` which also works when executing outside of the directory of the package.