# Composer: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, composer-php

I have my own functions stored in the `helpers.php` file in the `helpers` folder relative to the `composer.json` file.

```
<?php

function config (string $params){}

function redirect() {}
```

In the file `composer.json` this file is included in `autoload`

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\" : "./app"
    },
    "files": [
      "helpers/helpers.php"
    ],
  "scripts": {
    "delete-all-tables": "App\\Migrations\\DeleteTable::deleteAllTables",
  }
}
```

I used `composer-dump` after connecting `helpers`.

I am using `config ()` at this location:

```
<?php

namespace App\Migrations;

use App\Components\Migration;

class DeleteTable extends Migration
{
    public static function deleteAllTables()
    {
        $param = config('db.dbname');

        $instance = new self();
        $instance->con->query("DROP DATABASE " . $param . "; CREATE DATABASE " . $param . "; USE " . $param . ";");
    }
}
```

When using my functions in the `Migration` class not through the composer, everything works correctly, but when calling `scripts` commands through `Terminal`, the `config` function is not executed. Then the error appears:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function App\Migrations\config() in D:\OSPanel\domains\myshop\app\Migrations\DeleteTable.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(324): App\Migrations\DeleteTable::deleteAllTables(Object(Composer\Script\Event))
#1 phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(218): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->executeEventPhpScript('App\\Migrations\\...', 'dele
teAllTables', Object(Composer\Script\Event))
#2 phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(101): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Object(Composer\Script\Event))
#3 phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/ScriptAliasCommand.php(64): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript('delete-all-tabl...', true, Array)
#4 phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(245): Composer\Command\ScriptAliasCommand->execute(Obje in D:\OSPanel\domains\myshop\app\Migrations\Delet
eTable.php on line 11
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Are there any options for solving the problem without using helpers in the class?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Namespace issue, I'd say. Try `\config` at the call site.

Comment: It would help having an actual [mcve]. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. That said, the error message is pretty clear which function (and in which namespace!) it's trying to call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer.json Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67265846/composer-json-fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function)

Comment: @msbit , my function isn't in class, it's in the `helpers.php` file

Comment: Yep, I believe you. Have you tried prepending the backslash, just in case?

Comment: Scratch that, it's not related. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#defining-scripts):

> Callbacks can only autoload classes from psr-0, psr-4 and classmap definitions. If a defined callback relies on functions defined outside of a class, the callback itself is responsible for loading the file containing these functions.

so any files normally included as part of a `files` autoloader type won't be included in this specific case.

As I see it, to get around this you have two options:

- Move the helper functions into a helper class as `static` member functions and have that loaded via the Composer autoload mechanism (either psr-0 or psr-4)
- Determine the location of the `helpers.php` file and `require` that in the migration file

For the first, it would look something like (in `app/Helpers.php`):

```php
<?php

namespace App;

class Helper {
  static function config (string $params){}

  static function redirect() {}
}
```

which would be called thus:

```
\App\Helpers::config('db.dbname');
```

In the second, taking inspiration from [37925437](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925437/how-to-get-the-root-package-path-using-composer), your `DeleteTable.php` could end up something like:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Migrations;

use App\Components\Migration;

class DeleteTable extends Migration
{
    public static function deleteAllTables()
    {
        require(dirname(\Composer\Factory::getComposerFile()) . '/helpers/helpers.php');

        $param = config('db.dbname');

        $instance = new self();
        $instance->con->query("DROP DATABASE " . $param . "; CREATE DATABASE " . $param . "; USE " . $param . ";");
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this line `require(dirname(\Composer\Factory::getComposerFile()) . '/helpers/helpers.php');` to the constructor of the `Migration` class and it worked! WOW!!! Thank you very much again !!